# Extracting and collating data from multiple columns in Excel 2003

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel-2003, pivot-table

First of all I have tried a lot but failed to get a solution for the following problem and I hence request all the superusers to help me with their best if possible....

I tried unpivoting but it did not work.

The link to my file is:

https://app.box.com/s/sseqs960dlyvw12ud2mv

I am using excel 2003.

My query goes like this:

I need to find out "total lifted quantity"(i.e. the sum of 'first state lifted quantity'+'second state lifted quantity'+'third state lifted quantity') for each "state" for each "size" and each "grade".

However when I am applying a pivot table (as seen in Sheet1) it is not giving data in lucid form. I don't want to split the data for three states in three different tables (as seen in Sheet 4).

Comment: Is there a reason that you need the data to be split into First, Second, and Third? Or is that just how it's input?

Comment: Actually I have prepared this proforma and the users will be filling this report and the summary. YES the quantity is divided into three parts (i.e. 3 states) which are first reported separately and it is then required to be consolidated and summed for each state (and subdivided into for each sector and each size and each grade). For just a single state pivot table would be a great option but not when  it is required to be summed for three states.